# What is the different between laravel WITH and LOAD

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, laravel-query-builder

Sometime I'm confused when should I use `with` or `load` methods.

```php
$list = Category::with('parent')->paginate(50);
```

```php
$category = Category::find(1)->load('parent');
```

I use this code and it works fine.

But I dont have clear understanding if I should use `load` instead of `with` or Inverse.

**Why shows me the error.**

Comment: `composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev` and check the queries that are being ran.

Comment: what error? ... if you are building the query and you know you need to load the relationship use `with` to eager load them ... if you already have a result set and were not in a position to build the query and add the `with` you can use `load` after the fact to 'lazy eager load' the relationships

Comment: Timing is the main difference. `$model1 = Model::with('relation')->first()` would be equivalent to `$model2 = Model::first(); $model2->load('relation');`. Comparing them: `$model1 == $model2`, or `$model1->toArray() === $model2->toArray()` are both `true`. They both load the `relation` as a property, but at different timings in the Model's lifecycle.

Comment: Also, `Model::find(1)->load('relation')` creates a new Builder (Query) instance. If you called `->get()` after `->load()`, you'd get **every `Model` record from your DB.** This is a caveat of `::find()` returning a Model, and `->load()` starting a new query, since Models can also be queries. It's weird, but simply don't do that 